# Difference between Microsoft .NET Framework Version vs ASP.NET Version on Server Error Page

Tags: asp.net, .net

In an ASP.NET application, if a server error is encountered, an error page is displayed. On the bottom of this page is a line which reads:

```
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.81.0
```

What exactly does the "Microsoft .NET Framework Version" and "ASP.NET Version" refer to? It's my understanding that the "Microsoft .NET Framework Version" is the CLR version. However, I can't seem to find a decent explanation of this anywhere. Thank you!

Comment: ASP.NET and .NET version numbers are not necessarily the same. Unless you have a strong suspicious your error is related to the particular version of something, you can probably ignore it.

Comment: So what do the number actually refer to? I'm troubleshooting an issue only occurring in certain environments.

Comment: One is the version number of the .NET Framework, the other is the version number of ASP.NET.